# Why do the views extend wider than the screen?

Tags: swiftui

**Edit: Substitute your "system name:" of choice. "pencil.circle" works fine. "edit" is not a valid SF Symbol.**

(I've simplified my code so you can cut and paste. That's why you see .frame, resizable, etc. where much simpler code might your first instinct.)

I have created a view which is a vertical list of row items (table view).
Each row item has a horizontal view with two images inside it.
The images take up too much space and do not fit correctly on the screen:

```
import SwiftUI

    @main
    struct StackOverflowDemoApp: App {
    
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                TandemView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct PaddedImageView: View {
        let color: Color = .red
    
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                color
                Image(systemName: "edit")
                    .resizable()
                    .padding()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    struct TandemView: View {
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .resizable()
                    .background(Color.orange)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                PaddedImageView()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 80)
            }
            .padding()
            .fixedSize()
    
        }
    }

    struct TandemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            TandemView()
        }
    }
```

[image: RealEstateBug]

The above is the closest I can get to the desired layout (it just needs to fit horizontally). I experimented with GeometryReader but that did not produce desired results.

Here are some things I tried:

0. The code as provided
1. NoConstraintsOnPencilOrHStack
2. NoConstraintsOnTandemView
3. NoConstraintsOnImageInPaddedViewButWithFrameConstraint

[image: SameAsProvidedCode]
[image: NoConstraintsOnPencilOrHStack]
[image: NoConstraintsOnTandemView]
[image: NoConstraintsOnImageInPaddedViewButWithFrameConstraint]

I am trying to get a row view which consists of two Images (my actual source consists of UIImage objects) that fits within the width of the screen.

**Edit:**
After Accepting cedricbahirwe's spot-on response, I was able to simplify the code further.  New results:

[image: CleanedUp]

I added at the top level

```
 TandemView()
      .padding(.horizontal)
```

I removed:

```
 //       Spacer()
```

at the end of PaddedImageView

updated TandemView -- changed both frames and removed 3 lines:

```
struct TandemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                .resizable()
                .background(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
//                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
            PaddedImageView()
                .frame(height: 80)
        }
//        .padding()
//        .fixedSize()

    }
}
```

Comment: So you want both images to be equal width?

Comment: No. Ultimately the first view is a square and it is the same height as the second view. There could be spacer in between the two. The second view is typically 320 x 80 but doesn't need to be fixed length. It could expand the width of the screen allowing the width/height of the first image.  A normal height would be 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the layout of `PaddedImageView` View, you can actually remove the `Spacer` since it is not needed there.

So change

```
struct PaddedImageView: View {
    let color: Color = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color
            Image(systemName: "edit")
                .resizable()
                .padding()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

to

```
struct PaddedImageView: View {
    let color: Color = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color
            Image(systemName: "edit")
                .resizable()
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:
`SwiftUI` Engine infers the layout of your view from the implementation of the `body` property. It's recommended to have one Parent View inside the body property.

Comment: Impressive! Good eye. After your fix, I just had to adjust the frame for the Image in TandemView to  .frame(width: 80, height: 80)

Comment: Yeah, that was it,